# Xubuntu 17.10: screen flickering on wake up

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, intel-graphics, hp, flicker

I'm using Xubuntu 17.10 on an HP Elitebook 820 G2. Occassionally,
when the computer wakes up from sleep, the screen is flickering and
shearing until I restart the computer.

Information :

```
$ lspci | grep VGA 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel
Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)


$ sudo lshw -c video 
 *-display description:
VGA compatible controller product: HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Intel
Corporation physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 version: 09
width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 resources: irq:47
       memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff
       ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


$ modinfo i915 | grep driver filename:
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
parm: alpha_support:Enable alpha quality driver support for latest
hardware. See also CONFIG_DRM_I915_ALPHA_SUPPORT. (bool) parm:
use_mmio_flip:use MMIO flips (-1=never, 0=driver discretion [default],
1=always) (int)
```

Full hardware info:

```
System:    Host: arvid-HP-EliteBook-820-G2 Kernel: 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3
           Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP EliteBook 820 G2 v: A3009D510203 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 225A v: KBC Version 96.55 serial: N/A
           BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: M71 Ver. 01.08 date: 08/12/2015
Battery    BAT0: charge: 37.8 Wh 100.0% condition: 37.8/37.8 Wh (100%)
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5600U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3200 MHz 1: 2593 MHz 2: 2593 MHz 3: 2593 MHz 4: 2593 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 5500
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.14hz, 1920x1080@59.96hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) version: 4.5 Mesa 17.2.8
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-36-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM driver: e1000e
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: b0:5a:da:3e:eb:3d
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 94:65:9c:a2:e1:f3
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 512.1GB (29.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: MTFDDAK512MBF size: 512.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 160G used: 16G (11%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: 0.0C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 189 Uptime: 1:53 Memory: 2301.9/7852.1MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.37 

mode "1024x768"
    geometry 1024 768 1366 768 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    accel true
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : inteldrmfb
    Address     : 0xb0011000
    Size        : 4227072
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 1
    YPanStep    : 1
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 5504
    Accelerator : No
Version: 1:7.7+19ubuntu3
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
   1366x768      60.14*+  40.09  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96* 
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
fglrxinfo: command not found
The program 'nvidia-settings' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
H/W path           Device     Class          Description
========================================================
                              system         HP EliteBook 820 G2 (N4E93PC#ABF)
/0                            bus            225A
/0/d                          memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/7                          processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/7/8                        memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/7/9                        memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/7/a                        memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/6                          memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/0                          memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/0/0                        memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
/0/0/1                        memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
/0/100                        bridge         Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
/0/100/2                      display        HD Graphics 5500
/0/100/3                      multimedia     Broadwell-U Audio Controller
/0/100/14                     bus            Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0        usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/3                 bus            USB2134B
/0/100/14/0/3/2               bus            Keyboard Hub
/0/100/14/0/3/2/2             input          Apple Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/3/2/3             input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/4                 communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/5                 generic        VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
/0/100/14/0/7                 multimedia     HP HD Webcam
/0/100/14/1        usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/3                 bus            USB5534B
/0/100/16                     communication  Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
/0/100/19          enp0s25    network        Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
/0/100/1b                     multimedia     Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                     bridge         Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.1                   bridge         Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/1c.1/0                 generic        RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.3                   bridge         Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4
/0/100/1c.3/0      wlo1       network        Wireless 7265
/0/100/1d                     bus            Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
/0/100/1d/1        usb1       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                 bus            USB hub
/0/100/1f                     bridge         Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                   storage        Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
/0/100/1f.3                   bus            Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
/0/1               scsi1      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0         /dev/sda   disk           512GB MTFDDAK512MBF-1A
/0/1/0.0.0/1       /dev/sda1  volume         80GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2       /dev/sda2  volume         377GiB Extended partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2/5     /dev/sda5  volume         214GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2/6     /dev/sda6  volume         162GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3       /dev/sda3  volume         19GiB Windows NTFS volume
/1                            power          SB03046
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
ii  gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64                 1.5.14-2ubuntu1                          amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - introspection data
ii  i965-va-driver:amd64                  1.8.3-1ubuntu1                           amd64        VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family
ii  ibus                                  1.5.14-2ubuntu1                          amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - core
ii  ibus-gtk:amd64                        1.5.14-2ubuntu1                          amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+2 support
ii  ibus-gtk3:amd64                       1.5.14-2ubuntu1                          amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+3 support
ii  libcilkrts5:amd64                     7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2                         amd64        Intel Cilk Plus language extensions (runtime)
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                   2.4.83-1                                 amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64                 2.4.83-1                                 amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-radeon1:amd64                  2.4.83-1                                 amd64        Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                    17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                   17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libgles2-mesa:amd64                   17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                    9.0.0-2.1build1                          amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libibus-1.0-5:amd64                   1.5.14-2ubuntu1                          amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
ii  libmpx2:amd64                         7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2                         amd64        Intel memory protection extensions (runtime)
ii  libosmesa6:amd64                      17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:amd64                1.0+git20151227-2                        amd64        Texture compression library for Mesa
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64            17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-utils                            8.3.0-5                                  amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64              17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                1:7.10.0-1                               amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel              2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1          amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau            1:1.0.15-2                               amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon             1:7.10.0-1                               amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000] Reserving Intel graphics memory at 0x00000000ac800000-0x00000000ae7fffff
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
[    0.060000] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x3d, stepping: 0x4)
[    0.060000] Performance Events: PEBS fmt2+, Broadwell events, 16-deep LBR, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
[    0.070318] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.220611] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    3.346832] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    3.380021] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    3.380021] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    3.380021] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    3.380021] vgaarb: loaded
[    4.101541] vesafb: mode is 1366x768x32, linelength=5504, pages=0
[    4.101542] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[    4.101543] vesafb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    4.101550] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xb0000000, mapped to 0xffffa306c1800000, using 4160k, total 4160k
[    4.101632] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    4.101642] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x11142120
[    4.101643] intel_idle: v0.4.1 model 0x3D
[    4.101796] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    4.660091] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
[    4.662595] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    4.685429] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    4.689134] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    4.689371] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    4.756092] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
[    4.853478] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    4.853478] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    5.117932] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    5.118352] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    5.118423] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    5.126713] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    5.202540] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    5.202600] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    5.390926] systemd-sysv-generator[241]: stat() failed on /etc/init.d/spesserviced, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    5.499350] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    6.045161] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    6.045162] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    6.082493] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    6.091591] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x184
[    6.305819] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    6.305821] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    6.305822] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    6.305823] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    6.356913] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
[    6.357023] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input15
[    6.357113] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input16
[    6.357196] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input17
[    6.549711] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011002270d00
[    6.550128] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
[    6.732728] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    7.164739] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    7.178227] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input24
[    7.178360] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input25
[    7.178440] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input26
[    7.178517] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input27
[    7.178594] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input28
model       : 61
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
model       : 61
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
model       : 61
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
model       : 61
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     7.346] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     7.346] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[     7.347] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     7.347] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.347] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.347] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     7.347] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     7.365] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     7.366] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     7.373] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.373] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[     7.375] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     7.375] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     7.375] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.375] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     7.380] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     7.381] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     7.381] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
[     7.456] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[     7.456] (II) modeset(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[     7.456] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[     7.456] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     7.456] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     7.485] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     7.485] (II) Unloading vesa
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[     7.636] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[     7.637] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[     7.637] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[     7.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event18)
[     7.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event19)
[     7.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event20)
[     7.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event21)
[     7.770] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event22)
[     8.032] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[     8.033] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event9)
[     8.033] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Dock Line Out (/dev/input/event10)
[     8.033] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
    Release Date: 08/12/2015
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP EliteBook 820 G2
    Serial Number: 5CG5384C4L
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: 225A
    Serial Number: PEVDL00WB9H14O
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Serial Number: 5CG5384C4L
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 00361611
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 00361612
    Manufacturer: 33-42
    SBDS Serial Number: 00FF
    SBDS Manufacture Date: 2015-08-12
cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 17.2.8

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
Support status summary of 'arvid-HP-EliteBook-820-G2':

You have 1646 packages (78.4%) supported until juillet 2018 (Canonical - 9m)

You have 3 packages (0.1%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 451 packages (21.5%) that are unsupported


Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  14
ccm                    20480  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
joydev                 20480  0
cmac                   16384  1
hid_apple              16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_apple
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
bnep                   20480  2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             544768  41 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm                   585728  0
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
arc4                   16384  2
aesni_intel           188416  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
iwlmvm                385024  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
mac80211              782336  1 iwlmvm
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
iwlwifi               253952  1 iwlmvm
input_leds             16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
serio_raw              16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mei_me                 40960  0
cfg80211              614400  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
mac_hid                16384  0
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
hp_wireless            16384  0
tpm_infineon           20480  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
i915                 1822720  4
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               147456  0
ahci                   36864  3
e1000e                249856  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   360448  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
```

I've found no suggestions that seems to apply to my case so I haven't
tried anything.

Comment: I see same. 90%of time I can solve by using keyboard shortcuts to change from one workspace to another. After one or two changes, thr video rights itself. If you don't have keys for tgat. Learn how to define them.